# Java Events - How to send extra information to it?

Tags: java, events

I am a C# dev but currently working on Java. In C# the events have two arguments: the eventArgs - information about the event iself - and the sender, which is information about the object who fired the event.

Java has a slightly different approach, each event handler is a class (nested or not). I decided for creating no-nested classes because of code cleanness. 
What happens is that I am having problems because I **can't access some information about the object that fired** this event nor **access to some elements of the class** (other objects that may be useful for calculation).

How can I address these 2 issues?

Thanks,
Oscar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second issue is resolved either by going back to nested classes (unlike C#, nested classes in Java have access to the fields of the outer class, including non-static and private fields) or by passing an appropriate reference to the constructor of an event handler (if it's a single object that you want to have access to when processing an event).

Comment: Passing the reference to the constructor of the event handler is a clever idea, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

An *event* in Java is not a special language feature and so you're free to design your event classes as you like - as long as you do not have to use given event classes from a certain framework or library.

If you want to have an event that knows it's creator, you may code it like this:

```
public class Event<T> {
  private T sender;
  private String message;
  public Event(T sender, String message) {
    this.sender = sender;
    this.message = message;
  }
  public T getSender(){return sender;}
  public String getMessage(){return message;}
}
```

and fire it like this:

```
private void fire(String message) {
  for(Listener listener:listeners) {
    listener.notify(new Event<Sender>(this, message));
  }
}
```

(assuming, `this` is a instance of the fictitious `Sender` class and you have a collection with Listeners for your events)

---

A `JButton` sends an `ActionEvent` to all registered `ActionListeners`. The constructor of this event takes the `sender`, which is the button object that caused the event. It provides a `getSource()` method to get it from the event, so

```
if (event.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
   JButton sender = (JButton) event.getSource();
}
```

will actually give you the button. The button again knows its "container", usually a `JPanel`. `getParent()` is the method to actually get it from the button (or any other component).

Another trick, if you want to know the dialog that holds a button, is to extend `JButton` and add a custom `parentWindow` field:

```
public class MyJButton extends JButton {
  private Window parentWindow = null;

  public MyJButton(Window parentWindow, String text) {
    super(text); // call the JButton constructor!!
    this.parentWindow = parentWindow;
  }
  // add all other constructors

  public getParentWindow() {return parent.Window;}
}
```

Use this class for your buttons and change the snippet from above to:

```
if (event.getSource() instanceof MyJButton) {
   Window window = ((MyJButton) event.getSource()).getParentWindow();
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is basically the observer pattern, right?
But the idea is that I would like to have this information in a "button clicked" event, so I would not like to have to reprogram everything :(
But thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Oscar - pretty sure, you're referring to the AWT or SWING framework within Java. They provide implementations of the observer pattern just like other frameworks (SWT, ..), but the event types may be different. Please tell the framework you actually use and we may provide better help.

Comment: As far as I know (I am really new in Java) I am using the Swing implementation.
I had already used the Observable class and Observer interface to create an observer pattern in a different part of the system. I could create a subclass of button which has a reference to a instance of observable (because of the single inheritance constraint in Java). Correct?
But maybe passing an instance of the object to the constructor may be a simpler way.